# How to set page number, rows per page of primefaces datatable?

Tags: events, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable, paginator

I am using primefaces datatable to show the users with radio buttons to make selection, now when page loads, table shows page 1 by default and 25 rows per page[this is expected], what i want now is if user sets 25 rows per page[by dropdown] and goes to say 4th page and selects the user, submits the form, now when page has got refreshed , i want user to see the table with previous page(4th and not 1st) and same no. of rows per page(25 and not 10).

Pasting below my datatable. [ my bean is ViewAccessscoped].

```
 <p:dataTable id="tableid" var="result"
                             styleClass="supertable top75"
                             paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {CurrentPageReport} {LastPageLink} {NextPageLink} {PageLinks} {PreviousPageLink} {FirstPageLink}"
                             value="#{bean.datamodel}"
                             tableStyleClass="pdatatable-table" rows="10"
                             rowsPerPageTemplate="10,25,50,100" paginator="true"
                             emptyMessage="No Users are available"
```

I tried setting "first" property of datatable by using below code in my bean but that din't work out, this is what i tried

added below event in xhtml

```
 <p:ajax event="page" listener="#{bean.onPageChange}"></p:ajax>
```

and method to bean

```
public void onPageChange(PageEvent event){

   pageindex=event.getPage();
   final DataTable  dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("loginasform:homeDataTable");
   dataTable.setFirst(pageindex); }
```

i do receive the value in bean but it still shows the default page and rows per page.

I am new to JSF and Primefaces , please let me know if you can help here.

Comment: Version info in questions os 'required'. Would have prevented the answer below

Answer (score 2):

To restore the state of your datatable(like it was before the refresh)...

Set p:dataTable attribute multiViewState="true" (refer the demo [Table State](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/tableState.xhtml))

And yet if it doesnt seem to work, change to @ViewScoped. Also confirm the version of primefaces you are using.

Comment: Hey Dennis, I think that attribute works with primefaces 6 and i have primefaces 5 , i am actually near to get what i  want , will post the answer once i am confirmed with the results

Comment: Indeed better to always post version info in answers